# Calculate trimmed mean for dataset rivers in R?

Tags: r, function, mean

Write a function to calculate trimmed mean for the dataset rivers.  The trim will be 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5.  Use that function to calculate the trimmed mean of rivers under the different trim values. (Hint: in that function, you may need to provide two arguments, e.g., x and y, where x represents the object “rivers” and y the different trim values)

Comment: I am winging this:  our_mean <- function (x) { y=mean(rivers [x, trim = 0.10])} 

paste (c("Trimmed rivers mean of", x, "is", y ))

Answer (score 2):

The task's hint tells us we need a function with two arguments, x and y, that represent the data we want to trim, and the several trim values. That gives the following structure:

```
# create our function
our_mean <- function(x, y) {
    ... # we'll do our magic here
}

# load dataset
data('rivers')

# run our function
our_mean( rivers, seq(0, 0.5, 0.1) ) # seq() will create a vector from 0.0 to 0.5 with a 0.1 step size
```

Now, let's focus on what should be inside our own function:

Fortunately, the base R `mean()`-function can already perform the trimming for us. We just need to supply it two arguments: which data to use (we have that available in `x`), and which **single** trim level we want. Our `y` is a vector of several trim levels, so we will have to iterate over `y` to handle each value individually:

```
our_mean <- function(x, y) {
    for( t in y ) {
        ... # calculate a single mean for a single trim level
    }
}
```

All that remains is just supplying the relevant variables to `mean()` and returning the result. Given your code idea, let's print it to the screen as text.

```
our_mean <- function(x, y) {
    for( t in y ) {
        cat(substitute(x), "mean trimmed to", t, "is", mean(x, trim = t), '\n')
    }
}
```

*(I've used `substitute(x)` to look up the name of the variable that was referenced for `x`, which in this case was `rivers`)*

The end result:

```
> # create our function
> our_mean <- function(x, y) {
+     for( t in y ) {
+         cat(substitute(x), "mean trimmed to", t, "is", mean(x, trim = t), '\n')
+     }
+ }
> 
> # load dataset
> data('rivers')
> 
> # run our function
> our_mean( rivers, seq(0, 0.5, 0.1) )
rivers mean trimmed to 0 is 591.1844 
rivers mean trimmed to 0.1 is 490.9469 
rivers mean trimmed to 0.2 is 459.9765 
rivers mean trimmed to 0.3 is 442.2456 
rivers mean trimmed to 0.4 is 429.9655 
rivers mean trimmed to 0.5 is 425
```